# Linux networking (gethostbyaddr)

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I am trying to get host information about the host with IP address **89.249.207.231**. I know that it exists, because when I type the IP address in my browser's url field it finds the page. Here is my code in C.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    struct in_addr addr;
    inet_aton("89.249.207.231", &addr);
    struct hostent* esu = gethostbyaddr((const char*)&addr),sizeof(addr), AF_INET);
    printf("%s\n", esu->h_name);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it, it gives "Segmentation fault". I can not understand the problem with my code.

Any hints and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: First check the `esu`. It is probably `NULL`.  Check it and if NULL, see the value of `h_errno ` for the exact error.

Comment: The value of h_errno is 1. Where can I find  the explanation for that error?

Comment: Use perror() ;) Also gethostbyaddr() is obsolete. Use getnameinfo() instead.

Comment: Thank you! I used perror() and it types "Operation is not permitted", but I can not understand what could cause such an error.

Comment: I don't think `perror` is good for these errors...use `herror` instead.

Comment: Yeah, you are right!

Comment: `herror` is obsolete (on Linux, which this question concerns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the host exists, you may not be able to extract its hostname.

For example, the following code, without the deprecated functions that you use gives the result `host=google-public-dns-a.google.com` whereas with your host address gives `could not resolve hostname`.

The reason of your segfault, is that `esu` is `NULL`, because the function could not resolve a hostname by the given IP.

Here is the code:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa;    /* input */
    socklen_t len;         /* input */
    char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST];
    
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    
    /* For IPv4*/
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("8.8.8.8");
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    
    if (getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &sa, len, hbuf, sizeof(hbuf), 
        NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD)) {
        printf("could not resolve hostname\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("host=%s\n", hbuf);
    }
    
    return 0;                                                  
}
```